# Cannot install mysql-server due to bad uninstallation of mysql

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, mysql, dependencies

I recently uninstalled `mysql` which I think I didn't do properly. I think I might have created a circular dependency.

Running `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` gives the following error:

```
Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-hpScKN/0-mysql-common_5.8+1.0.4_all.deb (--unpack):

subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: dpkg: error: unknown option --validate-version

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;
Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-LZDAv0/0-mysql-common_5.8+1.0.4_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am trying to remove packages in cache and dpkg

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql*.*
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql*.*
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mysql-common
sudo apt-get remove mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo dpkg -r mysql-client-5.7
sudo dpkg -r mysql-server-5.7
sudo dpkg -r mysql-common
sudo dpkg -r mysql
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

My `/var/cache/apt/archives` contains the following `.deb` files when I run `sudo apt-get install sql-server`

```
libaio1_0.3.110-5_amd64.deb                         mysql-common_5.8+1.0.4_all.deb
libevent-core-2.1-6_2.1.8-stable-4build1_amd64.deb  mysql-server_5.7.21-1ubuntu1_all.deb
lock                                                mysql-server-5.7_5.7.21-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
mysql-client-5.7_5.7.21-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb          mysql-server-core-5.7_5.7.21-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
mysql-client-core-5.7_5.7.21-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb     partial
```

Comment: did you try `sudo apt -f install` to see if apt can fix itself?

Comment: Can you copy-paste the *entire* command line output from your command into your question as an edit?  The exit status alone isn't enough to debug what's going on there's likely other error output before that.

Comment: @ThomasWard Added the lines

Comment: Well at first glance, you're trying to use mysql-common 5.8 and you will have some conflicts there with mysql 5.7.  Secondly, the maintenance script for mysql-common 5.8 is using syntax that doesn't exist in your system.  Where did you get mysql-common from and install it before?  It sounds like you've got mismatched repos or a custom install that was botched.

Comment: mysql-common5.8 is created when I am running `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`. I cleared all previous installations of mysqlserver, mysql-client and mysql-common; but the problem still persist.

Comment: When you used `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mysql-common`, you told `dpkg` to forget that the package had been installed...but you left all the files in place. Those files must be removed by hand.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked like this:

check if mysql-server is installed:

```
dpkg -l mysql-server
```

Access the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server
```

PHPMYADMIN remover - graphical database manager:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge phpmyadmin
```

stop MySQL service:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

remove one more package from MySQL:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-common
```

delete the mysql folder located in /var/lib/ with the command below:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```

Now:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
```

Checking again if MySQL is installed.

```
dpkg -l mysql-server
```

Now the result starts with "**un**", which means the package is no longer installed on the operating system.

Font: https://tipslegais10.blogspot.com/2013/01/desinstalar-mysql-no-linux-por-completo.html

I'm sorry. I don't speak english yet